# Macro to Convert Inline Image to Attachment - MS Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

When I take a snippet or screenshot of something I'm working on and need to send it in an e-mail (MS Outlook), I don't always want to paste it in-line in the HTML body of the e-mail. There are times where I would like to add the image as an attachment.

In the interest of making this repetitive task a bit more efficient, is it possible for me to accomplish this without having to first save the image/screenshot and add an attachment manually? Perhaps a macro to convert an in-line image in my e-mail to an attachment on the same e-mail?

Downloading add-ons or plugin-ins is a no go; I work in a large corporate environment where this is near impossible to do.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by inline images? Images hosted on the remote HTTP servers and referenced by the HTML body? Or embedded image attachment referenced by the HTML body by their cid's? In the latter case, the attachments are already in the MailItem.Attachments collection.

Comment: The latter, I believe. The ideal scenario would be for me to paste an image into my email and then with the image selected, hit a macro which removes the inline image from the email body and adds it as a .png attachment. Is this possible?

Comment: You can simply loop through the MailItem.Attachments collection, check if the PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B` ) is set to true, and reset it back to false - this way the attachment will still be used in the HTML body, but Outlook will show the attachment in the list of attachments.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply convert an inline (embedded image) image into an attachment, you will need to save the inline attachment to a folder location, delete the inline attachment, and reattach the saved attachment.